# Find 'view' co-ordinates in vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm working on a modification to vis.js's Graph3d to do a filled line graph, like this:

[image: filled line graph]

The hard part - unsurprisingly - is working out the rendering order for the polygons. I think I can do this by checking whether a ray from the viewer to a given line B crosses line A:

[image]

In this example, since line A is "in the way" of line B, we should draw line A first. I'll use a snippet of code from [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) to check whether the lines cross.

However, I haven't figured how to find the position of the user's view. I kind of assumed this would be the camera object, so wrote a little bit of debug code to draw the camera on the graph:

```
var camera = this._convert3Dto2D(this.camera.getCameraLocation());
ctx.strokeStyle = Math.random()>0.5 ? 'ff0000' : '00ff00';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(camera.x, camera.y);
ctx.lineTo(camera.x, camera.y+5);
ctx.stroke();
```

In fact, the camera co-ordinates as measured by this are always at 0,0,0 on the graph (which would be the far top right on the above screengrab). What I need, I think, is effectively the bottom of the screen.

How can I find this? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is still an active issue, but FWIW, `Graph3D` has internal handling of the sort ordering.

All graph points are sorted with respect to the viewpoint, using a representative coordinate called `point.bottom`. The rendering is then done using this ordering, with the most distant elements drawn first. This works fine as long as none of the elements intersect; in that case, you can expect artefacts.

Basically, all you need to do, is define `point.bottom` per graph polygon, and `Graph3D` will then pick it up from there.

If you are still interested in working on this:

This happens in [Graph3d.js](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/graph3d/Graph3d.js), method `Graph3d.prototype._calcTranslations()`.  For an example, have a look at how the `Grid` and `Surface` graph elements are initialized in `Graph3d.prototype._getDataPoints()`. The relevant code is:

```
obj = {};
obj.point = point3d;
obj.trans = undefined;
obj.screen = undefined;
obj.bottom = new Point3d(x, y, this.zRange.min);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using three.js for the graph rather than vis.js because of this issue, but hopefully it'll be useful to someone else. (If you're interested, you can see the finished graph at http://cycle.travel/map; plan a route, click the elevation icon, then click '3D'.)

Comment: Not a problem! I'm happy that you found something that works for you.

I think this graph type is a cool idea; it's on my TODO as of now.